# Is it a bad practice seeking a data in list by index multiple times?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin

I have like below code,

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val view = holder.view
    view.apply {
        name.text = list[position].name
        age.text = list[position].age
        address1.text = list[position].address1
        address2.text = list[position].address2
        zip_code.text = list[position].zip_code
    }
}
```

it's seeking the data multiple times to get each property, like name, age, address1..

And I'm wondered is it better assign the data to a variable and use it? like this,

```
val view = holder.view
val data = list[position]
view.apply {
    name.text = data.name
    age.text = data.age
    address1.text = data.address1
    address2.text = data.address2
    zip_code.text = data.zip_code
}
```

Assigning to new variable is cost more?

Please advise me which is better and why?

Comment: that depends on `list` implementation. in case of `arraylist` get(index) complexity is O(1) so both will have same performance.

Comment: If it is same complexity then the first one is better? because it saves the single variable

Comment: Even at `O(1)` complexity, accessing the element multiple times will have worse performance - unless the compiler or proguard or the runtime can optimize it to just one access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second is probably better due to 2 reasons:

1. You don't have to access the list at a specified index multiple times, but only once ([access costs depending on the actual implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322742/8073652))
2. it's much more readable and also less error-prone to reduce these duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
val view = holder.view
view.apply { list[position].also { data ->
    name.text = data.name
    age.text = data.age
    address1.text = data.address1
    address2.text = data.address2
    zip_code.text = data.zip_code
}}
```